# How can we redirect to new HTML static content with Apache and fall back to older CMS-based PHP version if not found? (nginx try_files)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, nginx, mod-rewrite

### The Problem :

We are in the process of replacing an old PHP-based web site (based on Statamic v1) with a SSG HTML version build with Gatsby.

The problem is : only a part of the existing pages must replaced, while the member space, and the `/login` and `/contact` pages must be preserved for now.

So i wonder how should i adapt the current `.htaccess` configuration with a new version *looking first* for the new static content found inside a specific directory (`public/`) or if not, falling back to the old `index.php?path=` method.

### Note :

With `nginx` this would be done with a `try_files` directive
so, this question is somehow related to : 
https://serverfault.com/questions/290784/what-is-apaches-equivalent-of-nginxs-try-files
but i absolutly don't understand the `balancer://app_cluster` stuff..

### The context :

Here is a simplified view of the directories as they must be served by Apache :

```
www/
├── index.php
├── (... more CMS files)
└── public
    ├── index.html
    ├── main.js
    ├── robots.txt
    ├── img
    │   ├── intro.jpg
    │   ├── logo.svg
    │   └── table.png
    ├── about
    │   └── index.html
    └── staff
        └── index.html
```

*Anything* into `public/` must be served *first*
without `/public` appearing into the final URL :

```
URL : /img/intro.jpg => /public/img/intro.jpg (rewritten as /img/intro.jpg)
```

And every URL matching an `/index.html` page must be rewritten without it :

```
URL : '' or '/' => /public/index.html (rewritten as '')
URL : /staff or /staff/ => /public/staff/index.html (rewritten as /staff)
```

Every file not found are redirected to `/index.php?path=...` as allready done now.

### The Question

Is it only possible with Apache without ressorting to two separate sub-domains and virtual_hosts.. to separate the 2 sources ?
I guess that yes, given Apache incredible powers, 
but as i'm more accustomized with the nginx way-to-do now, i really need your help here !! :)

### Current configuration

(don't ask me why)

```
# Turn on the Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine On

# PERMANENT HTTPS REDIRECTION
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_SCHEME} =http
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# If you're running in a subfolder (like http://example.com/statamic),
# add that here. E.g. /statamic/
RewriteBase /
# Remove trailing slashes from your URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(\?.*)?$ $1$2 [R=301,L]

# Remove the index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I really welcome short answers saying : _yes it's possible_, or _no.. because.._  

That would really help me to decide if i must replace Apache with nginx, or with a custom proxy written in node.js (i could do that for sure, but it could hurt the performances as well when serving the static assets..)

So any help will be greatly appreciated ! :)

Comment: Note : 
The content hierarchy tree could be reversed, and we could explore as well the possibility of having the static site as root, and the legacy PHP CMS in a subfolder, maybe it could be more efficient..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, they key requirement is to serve static content in `public/` if it exists, and if not, pass the request to `index.php`.

That requirement is relatively easy to handle.  The order of the rules is important, as they are applied in sequence for each incoming request.  We can do the test for the `public/` content first, so if it exists there we will preferentially return it and stop processing.  If the request does not match that test, processing will continue on to the `index.php` redirect.

```
RewriteEngine On

# If the requested file or directory exists in public/, internally redirect
# there (internally means no actual new http request, and the URL in the
# browser does not change).  Use OR flag to OR the 2 conditions, instead of
# the usual implicit AND.
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ public/%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

# If the requested file does not exist, and is not a directory, pass the
# request to index.php, appending any query string.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Note you mention:

> Every file not found are redirected to /index.php?path=... as allready done now.

Just to be clear, that is *not* actually what the `.htaccess` you included does now.  That rule simply passes the request to `index.php`, without a `path` parameter (though including any existing parameters that are already in the request).  Your `index.php` can access - and surely is already accessing - the real requested path using `$_SERVER` variables.  But if you do actually want to now append the path to the query as you describe, you'd have to amend that rule to something like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Another side note - there is a lot of extraneous stuff in both the question and the `.htaccess` which I think confuses the issue and is maybe why you haven't had a great response here.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Your response is really clear and i'm pretty sure it works even if i don't bother to test it right now. 
It came a little bit too late but i'm very grateful anyway : somebody will surely find it useful :)